# Network configuration from within a program

Tags: networking

Are there any program accessible equivalents to network configuration tools such as  'ifconfig', 'iwconfig' e.t.c.?

I am looking for an elegant method of accessing the functionality and information these provide from within a program.

Comment: Which type of program needs to know these information? There are different solutions for different languages, e.g. use `getifaddrs` to get the IP's from within C code..

Comment: FYI... `ifconfig` is not recommended for use under linux, as it has bugs and is no longer maintained... use `ip addr show`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ifconfig` and friends obtain most of the information they show by calling various [ioctl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ioctl)'s on sockets. I recommend reading the source of `ifconfig` and other tools to see exactly what they do. But in most cases, it'll be easier to `popen` an `ifconfig` command.

Note that in both cases, your program will have to be ported to different unix variants. Neither ioctl nor the output format of ifconfig and other commands is portable.

An advantage of using ioctl's is not depending on external tools. On Linux, you can count on `ifconfig` and `route` being available, as well as `iwconfig` if there are wireless interfaces, but not necessarily `ip` (`ip` shows more information and its output is easier to parse, but most distributions don't install it by default, so it's actually not a good idea for portability).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hints everyone...I'm already getting to know the 'ip' utility and reading about it in 'Linux Advanced Routing & Traffic Control HOWTO' by 
Bert Hubert. It's much neater than 'ifconfig'. Next step might be to get the source and have a peek in there to get ideas about performing the queries from within my program.